# Disk Partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

I have recently installed Kubuntu as my laptop's only os. I have a 500gb disk space. Everything is working fine. The problem I think is maybe with the disk partitioning. As I only have 100 gb allocated to my machine and the rest I can't access.
Anyone please help me with the problem. I am not using dual boot. I want to gey access to my whole disk space as in windows with different drives(e.g c:, e:).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linux never used "drive letters" and probably never will. Please describe your system, how many physical drives, etc. and how did you install Kubuntu so that you have only 100GB...

Comment: Also, did you partition the Kubuntu drive as MSDOS or as GPT? MSDOS is limited to four primary partitions and GPT can have many partitions. Most people use GParted or Gnome-Disks for partitioning in Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed the system from a usb flash drive. I did disk partition manually. I had to configure two drive. On the
/Dev/sda I made the changes(swapping,root,home) but did not do anything with the /dev/sdb.                               I installed drive as GPT ext4. I am a complete newbie to linux. I would be glad if you please explain the concept of disk partition.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Edit your question and add all the information you wrote in the above comment. Then take two screenshots of the app gparted, one for `sda` and another for `sdb`. Upload these images in imgur.com. add links to these images in your question using the edit window.

Answer (score 0):

From the desktop:

- Click the button in the bottom left corner. It will look like a group of circles that form a square.
- This will open the apps menu. Find the app named `gParted`. The apps should be in alphabetical order, so it should not be very difficult. Click it.
- Once the application opens, find your Ubuntu OS partition in the list. It will most likely start with `/dev/sda1`, or occasionally `nvmon..` for M2 storage devices. If you have multiple SSDs / hard drives, it could also be '/dev/sdb1'. Select it.
  To edit the partition, you use the commands in the drop-down menus. They act on whichever drive is selected.

Once you see the GUI, you'll get it. It is pretty much self explanatory.